# Is it possible to call another classes method variables from the main class?

Tags: java, class, variables, instantiation

i have recently started programming in Java and have run into a problem that im not too sure of how to search up an answer for. So heres the short version:
I have a class called test(for the sake of the question) with public variables and public methods which have their own variables. In my main class i can create an object to call the test class variables, but can i call the variables that have been used in the methods from that class?

Comment: Can you show relevant code to show what you are describing? If I am understanding correctly, then you have declared local variables in your method that can only be accessed/used in that method. If you want to access the values later, you should save the values in instance variables.

Comment: We need to see code! We're not magicians ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you would have to store that variable as a member variable of the class. For example:

```
public class Test {
    public int b;

    Test() {
        int a = 1;
        b = 2;
    }
}
```

So in your other class, you could get the value of `b` like this:

```
Test test = new Test();
int valueOfBInTest = test.b;
```

But there is no way to retrieve the `a` variable that was used in the constructor of `Test` because that variable was forgotten at the end of the `Test` constructor. This is because of something called scope. The `b` variable has a scope of the instance of a class, so as long as that instance of the `Test` class is around, you can retrieve `b`. But since the `a` variable is declared in the `Test` constructor, it is only available in the constructor of `Test`. To be clear, the same thing will happen in any method of `Test`. If you declare a variable inside the method, that variable will be lost when that method is finished.